# Guard taking too long to run tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, minitest, spork

I'm working on a Rails app with a MiniTest suite on Mac OS 10.8.4, with Spork and Guard to run my tests on file changes, but Guard is taking way too long to respond to file system changes. Generally the tests will run right away for the first few file change events, but then they start to lag by a minute or more. The tests seem to always run, eventually, but not soon enough to really help speed up my workflow.

When I first set everything up, I wasn't having any problems, and I don't know what might have changed to cause this problem. I've tried all sorts of things to get things working fast again: forcing polling instead of using rb-fsevent; turning off Spork; disabling other guards; using guard-test instead of guard-minitest; recompiling Ruby per [this page](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X); running Guard with and without `bundle exec`...

I'm at a total loss and ready to give up. Any ideas?

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rack', '1.4.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.8'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.3.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'cocaine', '0.3.2'
gem 'paperclip', '2.4.3'
gem 'braintree'
gem 'thin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'rack-ssl'
gem 'rack-rewrite'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'koala'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'airbrake'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :staging, :test, :development do
  gem 'faker'
end

group :staging, :production do
  gem 'workless', '~> 1.1.3'
end

group :development, :staging, :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rr', :require => false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'mocha'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'spork-testunit'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-minitest', '0.5.0'
  gem 'guard-rake'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard', :require => false
  gem 'rb-inotify', require: false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: false
  gem 'rb-fchange', require: false
end
```

And my Guardfile:

```
interactor :off
notification :terminal_notifier, :sticky => true

guard 'spork', :wait => 60, :test_unit_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.*\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.*\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test }
end

guard :minitest, :drb => true, :all_on_start => false, :bundler => false do
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/functional/.+_test\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^test/unit/.+_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb')  { "test" }
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.+)\.rb$})                   { |m| "test/unit/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)\.rb$})              { |m| "test/functional/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb') { ["test/functional", "test/integration"] }
  watch('app/helpers/student_filter_helper.rb') { "test/unit/helpers/student_filter_helper_test.rb" }
end

guard 'rake', :drb => true, :task => 'test:scripts', :run_on_start => false do
  watch(%r{^app/assets/javascripts/(.+)\.[js|coffee]})
  watch(%r{^test/javascript/(.+)\.[js|coffee]})
end

guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|html)$})
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|scss))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end
```

And test_helper.rb:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  require 'rubygems'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
  require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
  require 'rails/test_help'
  require 'capybara/rails'
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'rr'
  require 'ostruct'

  class ActionController::TestCase
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    include Devise::TestHelpers
    def setup
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end
    def teardown
      super
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
      Timecop.return
    end
  end

  class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    include Capybara::DSL
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

    def setup
      super
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    def teardown
      super
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
      Timecop.return
    end

  end

  class MockTwilioClient
    def method_missing(*args)
      self
    end
  end

end

Spork.each_run do
  require "#{Rails.root}/test/test_support"
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
end
```

Comment: What does your `spec_helper.rb` look like?

Comment: My recommendation to easily locate this kind of problems is to always set specific gem versions in your Gemfile, and manually upgrade them through your VCS.

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having a similar problem with slow response from Guard